# What is the difference between ‘If there was’ and ‘If there were’?

Tags: grammar

If there was any truth in what you are saying, I would be worried.

If there were any truth in what you are saying, I would be worried.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

Technically the "were" form refers to the past, while the "was" form refers to the present. But in this use the "past" is the time, probably just a moment ago, when the other person said whatever s/he said. In both cases this is in the subjunctive mood, denying implicitly that there in fact **is** any truth in " what you are saying". Thus in this specific case, there is no significant difference in meaning.